# using trigger with a function as default value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a three columns; `apps_id(INT)PK`, `app_title(VARCHAR)` and lastly an `app_key(VARCHAR)`.

PROBLEM:
I want the column `app_key(VARCHAR)` to get a default random integer not more than 10 digits and am using trigger for the first time

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_apps
  BEFORE INSERT ON apps
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET apps.app = ROUND((10000000000 -70)*RAND()) + 7;
```

Am getting an error  `Unknown system variable 'apps.app'`

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_apps BEFORE INSERT ON apps FOR EACH ROW SET new.column_name = ROUND((10000000000 -70)*RAND()) + 7;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `new` not `apps`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_apps
  BEFORE INSERT ON apps
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.app = ROUND((10000000000 -70)*RAND()) + 7;
```